# Google+ snippet thumbnail not showing

Tags: social-networking, thumbnails, google-plus

i have in google+ snippet in my website, to sharing my website on google+, my code look like this

```
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="title of website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="my website url" />
<meta property="og:image" content="url image" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description of my website" /> 
</head>

<bod>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<g:plusone size="tall"></g:plusone></td>
</body>
```

i have also included facebook like, which rendering all meta tags (title,image,description). But, in case of google+, thumbnail image is not showing.

Need help !!

Answer (score 3):

What are the dimensions of your image? I standardised my thumbnails at 100x67 as they look right on Facebook, but Google+ wasn't showing them. I found that larger images will work with the same code, so I can only assume Google+ ignores little images for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

from google+ docs: https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/

> Images that are too small or not square enough are not included in the
>   +Snippet, even if the images are explicitly referenced by schema.org microdata or Open Graph markup. Specifically, the height must be at
>   least 120px, and if the width is less than 100px, then the aspect
>   ratio must be no greater than 3.0.

However i've been experimenting and this does not seem to be exactly right. Does anyone know the correct algorithm?