# Why does Google ignore my +1 page thumbnail?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, google-plus, google-plus-one, schema.org

Google +1 [button generator](http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/) implies I need to specify `<meta itemprop="image">` for the thumbnail.
Documentation page [says](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#plus-snippet) the following order is respected:

1. [Schema.org microdata](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html)

   ```
   <img itemprop="image" src="..."></img>
   ```
2. [Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/)

   ```
   <meta property="og:image" content="..."/>
   ```

**Neither of three, even combined, worked for me.**

Google Plus sharer ignores the image of my choice and shows a different image instead.
This is not a caching issue, as I have changed subdomains a couple of times just to check.

It [looks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7778794/458193) [like](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-plus-developers/rASWNWagWfw/YUDKWUgM2XQJ) Google +Snippet **prefers larger square images**.
I'm building an extensible engine so I need to know the requirements for sure.

What is the minimum size for a Google+ thumbnail?
Does it have to be square, or how close to square does it have to be?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/):

> [T]he height must be at least 120px, and if the width is less than 100px, then the aspect ratio must be no greater than 3.0

Comment: Thank you! This is correct, as I just tested `119px` vs `120px` and the latter worked. I read through the FAQ but I somehow missed this question, perhaps because there is no space between the paragraphs.